# AJAX.Добавление товаров в корзину

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код страницы с товарами:

```
<p>Товары</p>
            <?php  foreach ($productsList as $key) {?>
                  <table class="product" >
                    <tr>
                      <td class="img" rowspan="4">
                        <img class="img-for-modal" src="<?php 
                        if(file_exists(ROOT."/media/products-image/".$key['article'].".jpg") == true){
                        echo "/media/products-image/".$key['article'].".jpg";
                        }else{
                            echo "/media/products-image/not_found.jpg";
                            }?>">
                        <div class="modal">
                          <span class="close">&times;</span>
                          <img class="modal-img" src="<?php 
                        if(file_exists(ROOT."/media/products-image/".$key['article'].".jpg") == true){
                        echo "/media/products-image/".$key['article'].".jpg";
                        }else{
                            echo "/media/products-image/not_found.jpg";
                            }?>">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="product-info">
                        <article><?php echo $key['product_name']; ?></article>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="product-info">
                        <b>Артикул: </b><?php echo $key['article']; ?>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="product-info">
                        <b>Цена: </b><?php echo $key['price']; ?>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="product-delete">
                        <a href="" onclick="tobasket(<?php echo $key['id'].",".$_SESSION['id'];?>)">Добавить в корзину</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/js/basket.js"></script>
                <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php  echo $paginator->get(); ?>
    </div>
```

И есть код добавления:

```
function tobasket(product,user){
$.ajax({
    url:"/tobasket",
    type:"POST",
    data:({ product:product,
        user:user,}),
    dataType:"html",
    success: function Scs(response){
        alert('Товар добавлен в корзину!!!');
    }
});
```

}
Так вот собственно в чем вопрос.Я не знаю, и не понимаю, как можно сделать так, что бы товар, который добавил пользователь, отображался как добавленный???(PS:ТОвары добавляются в корзину не сессиями, а в бд)

Comment: Похоже надо как-то обновить виджет товара и/или корзины. В том же JS коде в методе success это надо сделать.

Comment: Отображался как добавленный где? В списке товаров с пометкой "уже в корзине"? В вынесенном блоке "в корзине 4 товара"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение достаточно простое.Т.К.Корзина хранится в бд даем запрос в начале страницы на запрос записей определенного юзера из бд:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
$basket = Db::getConnection()->query("
SELECT `product` FROM `product_basket` WHERE `user_id` = 
'".$_SESSION['id']."' ;");
$frombas = array();
$i=0;
while($row = $basket->fetch()){
$frombas[$i] = $row['product']; 
$i++;
}
}?>
```

Далее формируем ссылки согласно условию:

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($frombas) &&  in_array($key['id'], 
$frombas)){?>
<a>Убрать из корзины</a>
<?php }else{?>
<a>Добавить в корзину</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Ну и остается подшаманить с аяксом и функцией onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в базе статус для товара и проверяйте статус товара при загрузке его из бд.